# Inductor Behavior for Voltages

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, inductance

When a DC voltage source is connected with a pure inductor.
And the switch is closed

We get a change in voltage across inductor and along with it a also an attempt to change the current across the inductor.

We get equal and opposite voltage across inductor against the source voltage(Faraday and Lenz law) at $t=0$.

But then as time passes we get increase /change in current across the inductor at a constant rate.i.e, $$di/dt = V/L$$

Now when we connect AC with a pure inductor.

We have always changing voltage across the inductor and consequently always changing current across the inductor.

> **My Question**:$\quad$ Can I assume that for every infinitesimal change in voltage and current across the inductor in case of AC there will always be equal and opposite voltage across the inductor which will block the current initially for a while for that infinitesimal change and then will allow the current to change at a constant rate for that infinitesimal change of voltage and current?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you have in mind when you say   "block the current initially".  If your applied AC voltage is  $V= V_0\cos(\omega t)$, then   you  have at *all times* that
 $$
L\frac{di}{dt}=  V_0\cos(\omega t).
$$ 
Solving this gives 
$$
i(t) = \left(\frac{V_0}{L \omega}\right)\sin(\omega t)+ const.
$$

Comment: yes that is steady state but initially there will be transients. read this

Comment: AC voltage over ideal inductor is the data (given supply) and the current after a while is a 90 degrees delayed wave, the transient depends upon the contact timing referred to the AC voltage applied, if the contact happens at any AC voltage peak, there is no transient at all (the current becomes a 90 degrees delayed wave straight away) while the transient will be maximized when the contact is acchieved at any AC voltage zero crossing, the superimposed current will looks like an asymmetrical Gauss bell (very steeply at rising side).